# ASP.NET MVC 3 TextArea Default Content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Using the razor view engine, I have some code like the following:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Field, 20, 100, null)
```

How can I make this text area have a default value, i.e., what is normally in between `<textarea>` and `</textarea>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work if you just populate the `Field` property on the model with the default text. It will automatically insert the text when the markup is generated.

If you look at a view for edit, you see that this is how it works.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is to populate the model from within the controller and send it to the view.

```
// create a new model object
MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();

// populate the "Field" property in said object
model.Field = "this is my field text";

// send the pre-populated model to the veiw
return View(model);
```